# Angular2 CLI: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am learning Angular2. My folder structure is

```
src
    app
    assets 
      - images 
        -- img1.png
        -- img2.png
      - scss
        - main.scss
    styles.scss
angular-cli.json
package.json
```

Here I am importing **main.scss** in **styles.scss** like this

```
@import '../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css';
@import 'assets/scss/main.scss';
```

where **main.scss** contains a css property

```
background: url(../images/img1.png) center center no-repeat;
```

Here I am getting this error

```
./~/css-loader!./~/postcss-loader!./~/angular-cli/~/sass-loader!./src/styles.scss
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../image2/cal2.png' in 'D:\***\**\ui\src'
resolve '../images/img1.png' in 'D:\***\**\ui\src'
  using description file: D:\**\**\**\package.json (relative path: ./src)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
```

But, when I comment this line it is working fine. Help me what is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

While importing the main.scss the whole code is now in your styles.scss.
And from there the path would be:

```
'./assets/images/img1.png'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the relative path url('../assets/image.jpg') or the absolute path url('/assets/image.jpg' for the assets importing things. For the more clarify please visit the following links

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4778